# What came first: the Sun shining or the existence of helium?

Tags: star, the-sun, helium

This seems to be a chicken and egg problem, the sun begins shining due to hydrogen becoming helium, but it's odd that there was no helium initially without the stars.

Is my logic flawed?

(Note: First year astronomy student)

Comment: The helium abundance in the universe has hardly changed since after nucleosynthesis in the big bang which created about 23% He by mass. The figure *now* in the interstellar medium of our Galaxy is estimated to be   around 25%.

Comment: This may not be what you intended by this question, but the object that would become the sun was 'shining' before the p-p chain was able to activate in the core, due to gravitational contraction. This proto-sun of course developed from a cloud with ~24% He, so He existed before the sun on all accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Big Bang theory predicts that (depending what assumptions you choose) the [initial elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang_nucleosynthesis) were formed from 10 seconds to 20 minutes after the Big Bang.

The initial elements were

- mostly hydrogen
- some deuterium
- some helium-3 and helium-4
- a little lithium-7
- a couple of unstable isotopes that decayed to lithium-7 or helium-3.

As the linked Wikipedia article says

> Essentially all of the elements that are heavier than lithium and beryllium were created much later, by [stellar nucleosynthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_nucleosynthesis) in evolving and exploding stars.

So the answer to your question is: the Helium came first.

Comment: Correction: most helium came first.

Comment: @Florin Not sure what you mean; can you clarify? The answer says the helium came first, before stars. 75% of BBN output was hydrogen by mass.

Comment: Right. I'm just saying, some of the helium that exists today, a fraction of it, was made by stars, much later after the Big Bang.

Comment: @Florin Ok. Interestingly, most of the helium on Earth comes from radioactive decay of heavy elements.